# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443 when sending mail

Tags: sendgrid, file-not-found

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
(node:6768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6768) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !
And if possible add your tried code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please could you be more elaborate or better still add code snippet of your code for clearer understanding.

But from what I'm  suspecting, I think there is an asynchronous call that you made that was not handled properly which might be that you didn't catch an error exception after the call.
Always remember that **transport.sednmail()** is an asynchronous function and it returns a **promise**.
See example below:

```
// With ".then" function
transport.sendMail(email)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))


// With Callback function
transport.sendMail(email, (error, response) => {
   if(error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
   else{
       console.log(response);
   }
})
```

I hope this might be of little help to fixing the issue.

Comment: The question you're trying to answer is poorly written and needs more details, therefore it should not be answered until the OP describes the issue in more detail.